# What is the "religious organization" that motivated Abe Shinzo's killer?

Tags: religion, japan, prime-minister, assassinations

Looking into the motive of former prime minister Abe Shinzo's suspected killer, Yamagami Tetsuya, not many details are being given in the press, but there is mention of an unnamed religious organization.

To quote [one article from Le Monde](https://www.lemonde.fr/en/international/article/2022/07/09/what-we-know-about-shinzo-abe-s-suspected-killer_5989562_4.html):

> **Potential motivation**
>
> "The suspect stated that he held a grudge against a particular
> organization and that he committed the crime because he believed
> former prime minister Abe had a connection to it," police said Friday.
>
> They did not give the name of the organization in question, but
> Japanese media said it was a religious group, citing unnamed
> investigative sources. NHK and the Mainichi Shimbun said Mr.
> Yamagami's family had suffered troubles as a result of his mother's
> financial donations to the organization.

[An article from Reuters](https://www.reuters.com/world/asia-pacific/abe-killer-wielded-homemade-gun-grudge-over-mothers-bankruptcy-police-say-2022-07-09/) states:

> Yamagami was a loner who did not reply when spoken to, neighbours told
> Reuters. He believed Abe had promoted a religious group that his
> mother made a "huge donation" to, Kyodo news agency said, citing
> investigative sources.
>
> He told police his mother went bankrupt from the donation, the Yomiuri
> newspaper and other media reported.
>
> "My mother got wrapped up in a religious group and I resented it,"
> Kyodo and others quoted him as telling police. Nara police declined to
> comment on the details reported by Japanese media of Yamagami's motive
> or preparation.
>
> Media have not named the religious group he was reportedly upset with.

Which organization would this most likely be? And is there any public record of Mr. Abe being affiliated with or donating to a religious group?

<sub>Note: names intentionally listed with [family names first](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-japan-names-idUSKCN1VR1LE).</sub>

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assassination_of_Shinzo_Abe

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems to be the [Unification Church](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_Church), at least acording to [this article](https://english.kyodonews.net/news/2022/07/5d258295996e-urgent-unification-church-says-abe-shooters-mother-is-follower.html) by Kyodo News. However I have not found any proof that Abe was a member of that church or was related in any other way to it.

Comment: From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assassination_of_Shinzo_Abe: "Shinzo Abe, as well as his father Shintaro Abe and his grandfather Kishi Nobusuke, had longstanding ties to the Unification Church, a controversial new religious movement founded by Sun Myung Moon and based in South Korea. In 2006, during his first term as prime minister, Abe and several cabinet ministers sent congratulatory cables to the Universal Peace Federation (UPF), a church-linked non-governmental organization.[8] ...

Comment: ...Ten months before the assassination, in September 2021, Abe broadcast a five-minute speech as part of a UPF rally which included appearances by former U.S. president Donald Trump and other foreign dignitaries.[9]"

Comment: In general, I think it is appropriate to be a little bit suspicious of Wikipedia for something as dynamic as this, but the two quotes are backed by the Financial Times and Japan Press Weekly which are reasonably reliable sources.